# PHP: count the words in a DIV

Tags: php, count, words

I say PHP, because I have this snippet to count the words with PHP, maybe it's better with jQuery?

```
$words = str_word_count(strip_tags($myString));
```

I have a PHP page with static HTML mixed with some PHP variables like so:

```
<?php 
    $foo = "hello"; 
?>
<html>
<body>
    <div>total words: <?= $words ?></div>
    <div class="to_count">
        <?= $foo ?> <b>big</b> <i>world</i>, how <span>are</span> we today?
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried looking into PHP's output buffering and slipped an `ob_start()` and `$buffer = ob_get_clean();` around the .to_count DIV, but I can't seem to use the `$buffer` in the top section on the PHP page to count the words.

Any help to set me on the way is appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery and regex:

```
var wordCount = $.trim($(".to_count").text()).split(/\s+/g).length;
```

Comment: I might add a `.trim()` call before the `.split()` call there, just in case there are extraneous spaces. A quick test in web inspector shows that an indentation gets counted as a word otherwise.

Comment: yep, I am going the jQuery route as I have it loaded on all the pages where I need to wordCounts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can't use buffer before it is declared. If you do it will default to a value that isn't useful. I recommend counting the words before inserting them into the HTML and setting a variable with the count.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend building the content of the .to_count div before actually rendering it. Something like this:

```
<?php 
    $foo = "hello";
    $content = "$foo <b>big</b> <i>world</i>, how <span>are</span> we today?";
    $words = str_word_count(strip_tags($content));
?>
<html>
<body>
    <div>total words: <?= $words ?></div>
    <div class="to_count"><?= $content ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use output buffering to generate it. Which I think is tider than generating HTML in php.

```
<?php
ob_start();
$foo = "hello";
?>


<?php echo $foo ?> <b>big</b> <i>world</i>, how <span>are</span> we today?

<?php
    $myString = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $words = str_word_count(strip_tags($myString));
?>
<html>
<body>
    <div>total words: <?php echo $words ?></div>
    <div class="to_count">
        <?php echo $myString ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```